# Standard deviation formula for coefficients in multiple regression analysis

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, linear-regression, regression-analysis, standard-error

I am trying to understand how to calculate the individual deviation in this regression analysis table.

$(HH Size)_{se} =$ $stderr \over \sqrt{S_{xx}} $ $=$ $ {0.444400903 \over \sqrt{10}} = 0.14053$

The formula for $S_{xx}$ I am using:

$S_{xx} = {\sum x^2_i} - {1 \over n}{\sum x_i^2}$

Which you can see in the table is incorrect. The correct is $0.42270$

I would greatly appreciate if someone could tell me where I have calculated wrong or point me in the right direction.

[image: X and Y values]

[image: Regression Analysis Table]

Comment: Does it miss some information?

Comment: Someone anyone please help i can give some additional information ?